# How do I remove the git banner from the CLion editor?

Tags: ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

I don't know where I should ask for this. But I am trying to toggle/turn off this annoying git banner that appears at the left side of the CLion's editor.

[image: This-banner]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you correctly then it's the following functionality:

> **Track changes to a file in the editor﻿**
>
> You can also track changes to a file as you modify it in the editor. All changes are highlighted with change markers that appear in the gutter next to the modified lines, and show the type of changes introduced since you last synchronized with the repository. When you commit changes to the repository, change markers disappear.

To disable VCS markers in the gutter, deselect the `Highlight modified lines in gutter` option at: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Confirmation`.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/set-up-a-git-repository.html#track_changes

[image]